# window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS in JQgrid

Tags: angularjs, jqgrid, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I want to popup a Jira request popup, on click of an icon. This icon's css class is created in the JQ grid, in the column model. On the click of this icon, I need to open a Jira request popup.
can someone shed some light to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT - If you are talking about adding a JIRA issue collector to your own site, then this may help:

**Step 1**: Create an issue collector within Jira. Its a straight forward process and you can find the steps [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/using-the-issue-collector-802592637.html) or follow these steps:

- Login to Jira
- Choose > **Projects**.
- On the left of the Project Summary page, click the **Issue Collectors tab**. The Issue Collectors page is displayed, listing any issue collectors that have already been set up in your project.
- Click the **Add Issue Collector** button to open the Add Issue Collector page.
- In the top section of the Add Issue Collector page, fill in the fields provided (name, description, issue type, issue reporter, match reporter, collector browser info)
- In the middle section of the Add Issue Collector page (entitled 'Trigger'), specify the "Trigger text" and "Trigger style".
- In the lower section of the Add Issue Collector page (entitled 'Issue Collector Form'), specify the "Template" and "Message".
- Click the Submit button to save your changes.

After clicking the Submit button to save your new issue collector, a page containing code snippets is displayed. Use the code and information provided to embed your new issue collector into your web site. This is what the snippets looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://your_jira_url.co.za/s/a08716ba9b893434c0030633c043df94-T/asfxnf/74002/32f7d0e4f4445b0f89b4b03188c6e1bf/2.0.23/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector.js?locale=en-US&collectorId=*****"></script>
```

**Step 2**: Embed code snippet to your site (Add the below code to the html page you want the Jira popup to appear on)

```
<!-- This is the script for the issue collector feedback form -->

<PASTE CODE SNIPPET HERE>

<!-- This is the script for specifying the custom trigger. -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {
        "triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
            //Requries that jQuery is available! 
            jQuery("#feedback-button").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                showCollectorDialog();
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

**Step 3**: Add a trigger to call up the collector popup (same html page as above)

```
<a href="#" id="feedback-button" class='btn btn-primary btn-large'>Report feedback</a>
```

When you click the button, your Jira popup will appear.

Reference:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/advanced-use-of-the-jira-issue-collector-802592648.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16758783)

Comment: @CDspace I have amended my answer with code snippets and not just links. I hope this helps.